# How to configure appium on ubuntu operating system

Tags: android, node.js, ubuntu, selenium

Iam an automation tester having good experience in selenium automation tool and other tools.Now i want to implement mobile automation so i choose appium and started to install but faced number of issues and saw the same issues in several blog to rectify but couldnot.Kindly help me and below is the installation which i followed

1.Installed android sdk.

2.I just followed the instruction in the site http://appium.io/

brew install node # get node.js

npm install -g appium # get appium

npm install wd # get appium client

appium & # start appium

node your-appium-test.js

Now which brew gives me /home/user1/.linuxbrew/bin/brew , 
npm install -g appium but this gives me "Please try running this command again as root/Administrator." 
Then i installed nvm then npm to solve this issue but again the same above error.I tried my best but i couldn’t.Can any one help pls.

Below are the configurations
Os:Ubuntu
Mobile Os:Android

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like permissions issue with `.npm` folder in home directory that I faced also. Try following:

1. Make sure you installed **node** via [**homebrew**](https://github.com/Homebrew/linuxbrew#installation) (this will allow you to install Appium to a home directory without sudo). Do not install node via **apt**. Use `brew list` to check if **node** installed via **brew**.
2. Fix permissions issues with **.npm** folder (thanks for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16151707/3424319) answer): `sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.npm`
3. Install `Appium` with: `npm install -g appium`